# How can I call parent class overloaded function from derived class instance?

Tags: c++, generics

I have a base class with an implemented function and a pure virtual function which share a name, but not arguments. I can't call the function implemented in the base class from an instance of the derived class.

I've tried adding the function to the derived class instead of the base class and it works, but that would mean I have to add the function to every derived class instead of implementing it once in the base class.
I've also tried changing the functions name and it works. It seems to be due to a collision between the two overloaded functions.

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    virtual T some_function(int x) = 0;
    T some_function() {
    // some code
    }
}

class Derived final: public Base<int> {
    int some_function() {
    // some code
    }
}

int main() {
    Derived var = Derived();
    var.some_function(3);// Compilation error
}
```

The above code does not compile indicating that it doesn't find the function: some_function(int).

Comment: Not relevant for this example, but beware that `Derived var` will not behave polymorphically (it will not do virtual method calls but resolve them at compile-time based on the static type) - you would need a pointer or reference for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `some_function` in `Derived` hides the name `some_function` inherited from `Base`. You have to bring it back into scope with a `using` declaration:

```
class Derived final: public Base<int> {
public:
    using Base<int>::some_function;
    int some_function() {
    // some code
    }
}
```